How to save text formatting in python PYQT5
I'm trying to create a notebook application in PyQT5, and i want to save a text formatting (text size, text color, text font and more). Is there some easy option to do it?
Currect save and open code looks like this:
def savefile(self):
    try:
        self.save_file_url = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,"Save File", "", "Text Files(*.txt)")
        if self.save_file_url:
            with open(self.save_file_url[0], "a") as f:
                f.write(self.textarea.toPlainText())
    except:
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Error 001", "Something went wrong...")


def openfile(self):
    try:
        openfilename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName()
        with open(openfilename[0], "r") as file:
            self.textarea.setPlainText(file.readline())
    except:
        QMessageBox.about(self, "Error 002", "Something went wrong...")


def colorshortcut(self):
    return self.colorDialog()

I know this can't work in txt, but on this moment i doesn't have better solution.

what is textarea?

this is QTextEdit
